# Keep a folder of my repository on Github always synchronized with a folder from another repository

Tags: git, github

I have a repository in a folder that should contain the updated files from another repository on Github.

Is it possible? How do I create this structure? 
Submodules and sparse? So I can not change the folder name, it would be good.

This is not about clone, pull and push. It's about creating a folder in my repository and within this folder are the files from an existing folder in another repository. And every time I pull my repository files in the folder are updated with another repository.

**EDIT:** Forget it! Composer does not support submodules. (Unless there is another way than by submodule).

Answer (score 0):

Of course.
Just submit an automatic task in your system to run `git pull` in directory with repo.

Comment: Actually, I need to know the previous step to create the structure.

Comment: You clone repo using `git clone`, then `git pull` to keep it up to date. Depends on your platform you automate last step (or you can run it manually when required).